# Application to Display Quotes - Like Unix Fortune

Tags: windows, unix, terminal

I was wondering if anyone out there knows of any applications for Windows that are conceptually similar to the ['fortune' command in Unix systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortune_%28Unix%29) for Windows.

It would be nice if it allowed for custom quote\fortune settings and possibly customizable timers and randomization features.

I am willing to code it up myself, but I thought I'd see if it already exists first (and my searching has failed).

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick search on Google reveals these and more:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/fortune.aspx
- http://catfood.net/products/fortune/

Comment: Hmm, I think I may not have looked for 'fortune' by name when I was searching.

Comment: I'll give these a try, if they meet what I'm looking for I'll accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a Windows Fortune GUI for this myself in 2018, being unhappy with the existing implementations and intensively using Fortune for over 10 years.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/fortunewin32/

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.